# Ajax call not Working in Safari (5 & 6) sometimes. Working fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I know this question is asked many times, but I can't seem to get any of solutions working, (I have tried asyn:true,timeout, and also beforehand, etc).

Coming to the main issue:
The ajax call works often on Safari(ver 5 & 6)
it works all fine with Chrome & Firefox and even IE :),(MVC4 .Net C#).
It works just fine sometimes.

Following is the code I am trying:

```
function SaveData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SavePublicDraft")",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataDraft,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { alert('success'); },
            error: function(error) {  alert('error');   }
        });
    }
```

error response comes out to be empty.

Comment: Try changing `"@Url.Action("SavePublicDraft")"`  to  `"@Url.Action('SavePublicDraft')"`

Comment: @LShetty "@Url.Action('SavePublicDraft')"-- **Invalid Literal Character**,

Anyways url was rendering fine in my case..

Comment: Or the other way around => `'@Url.Action("SavePublicDraft")'`